# I am not able to play video in Picture in Picture mode using Jwplayer in swift 4 iOS

Tags: swift, jwplayer

I have tried below code, but its not working.. video is playing in PIP mode, but when I close PIP mode, video is not playing, application getting hanged.

Kindly Help me.
Thanks.

```
    jwPlayer?.playerView.pictureInPictureController?.delegate = self
        if #available(iOS 14.2, *) {
            jwPlayer?.playerView.pictureInPictureController?.canStartPictureInPictureAutomaticallyFromInline = true
        }
        jwPlayer?.playerView.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = true
        if jwPlayer?.playerView.pictureInPictureController?.isPictureInPictureActive == true {
            jwPlayer?.playerView.pictureInPictureController?.stopPictureInPicture()
          } else {
            jwPlayer?.playerView.pictureInPictureController?.startPictureInPicture()
          }
        playVideo()
```